# How to index a super class property in Objectify when super class is not an @Entity

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

**tl;dr:**
Is it possible to set an @Index to an Objectify entity property when the property is derived from a non-@Entity super class.

**Long version:**

A Java project contains abstract model classes which are used by the application instead of the concrete objects (Objectify entities). For each such model exists an @Entity that extends the model and adds specifics for the persistence layer (Objectify).

A simple example:

```
public abstract class UserModel {
  protected String givenName;
}

@Entity
public class UserImpl extends UserModel {
  @Id
  private Long id;
}
```

I chose this approach because i want to use the model classes independently from the persistence layer. Therefore the model classes cannot contain persistence layer specific annotations or code.

I know that in Morphia (a MongoDB ORM) it is possible to annotate an @Entity class like this:

```
@Indexes(@Index(value = "superGivenName", fields = {@Field("givenName")}))
```

Is it possible to achieve a similar effect in Objectify? It does not have to be a solution with annotations. It should however be possible to encapsulate the solution in the @Entity class.

Note: I will post a possible solution to this but I'm looking for something with more style / beauty, so please don't hesitate to answer when you have a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will find an answer that satisfies you. Objectify does not provide any behavior like this built in.

I assume you're concerned about Objectify annotations leaking into a client jar that you will distribute widely (android or some sort of rpc). I strongly recommend creating separate model classes for your API for the simple reason that it decouples your data model (which will change) from your API (which will likely change on a different schedule). It's hard to upgrade clients in the field. With separate classes, you can refactor your data model using your IDE without worrying about breaking backwards compatibility.

If you use http://projectlombok.org, there's almost zero boilerplate involved in the data transfer objects.

Comment: Honestly i was kind of hoping to attract your attention (check ;-)) and you would think that this is a good idea and add the possibility in one of the future Objectify versions. In general it would be great if we could define keys (including composite keys) annotation style. The entity would become the once place for all things related. Nowadays we still have to put composite indexes in the datastore index configuration file.

Comment: So what would you use to copy properties from Entity classes to DTOs (data transfer objects)? Some BeanUtils method or is there something better? Thanks for the lombok link, looks interesting.

Comment: I'm not particularly fond of this feature, because the situations in which it plausibly brings the most value - complex data models that you need to share across rpc boundaries - are exactly the same situations in which it causes the most trauma (nightmare upgrades and refactorings). So while it seems like a good idea at first, this kind of thing is actually an antipattern.

Comment: BeanUtils would eliminate the value of types. I use the constructor generated by lombok's `@Data` for final fields. Or you can use `@AllArgumentsConstructor` if you can't have final fields for some reason. Constructors give you type safety; if you add or remove fields, the IDE/compiler will know about it.

Comment: 1) Mh okay so you would copy the properties explicitly. I was hoping for a more generic solution. 2) I understand why adding additional indexes via annotation could become a problem. Since one can always create an antipattern somehow. I guess it could be handled by convention whether it becomes one or not. It doesn't have to be annotation though. I would be happy to put additional indexes right after the place (static constructor) where i register my entities with objectify.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to hide the super class properties which should be indexed in the @Entity class. Then use @OnLoad and @OnSave lifecycle callbacks to propagate the values between parent class and child.

Example:

```
public abstract class UserModel {
  protected String givenName;
}

@Entity
public class UserImpl extends UserModel {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  @Index
  private String givenName;
  @OnLoad
  void onLoad(){
      super.givenName = this.givenName;
  }
  @OnSave
  void onSave(){
      this.givenName = super.givenName;
  }
}
```